# Splitting polyline at multiple points using Mapinfo Pro?

Tags: line, mapinfo, splitting

I have a table of points and used the mapbasic app "Connect the Dots" to create a polyline.   The problem is it creates a single polyline and I want to split it up into separate lines so I can delete a few line segments.

Is there a way to take a single polyline and split it up using multiple points as the breaks?  (Mapcad did not have what I needed.)

Backstory: I am using this to make lines of GPS tracking data and sometimes we get a bad GPS read.  That bad read skews the line away then back.   Deleting the point can be problematic since we'd need to run the tool then delete the problems and the line created then run the line again.  I'd prefer to split the line up and select and delete the segments as needed.

Comment: Why can't you simply delete the wrong node from the polyline?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the *Disaggregate to Lines* option in the *Disaggregate* dropdown in the *Edit* group on the *SPATIAL* tab.

[image]

That is a feature of MapCAD. Not sure exactly when it was added.